# How to avoid duplicate IAM roles when deploying stackset to multiple regions

Tags: amazon-web-services, stack, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam

Hello I am a little rusty on cloudformation. But working on deploying a stacset across 15 accounts and multi region. I have tested in one region but when add another it bombs out.the reason is because I have iam roles that my lambda from a central account will assume. The child roles deploy in us-east-1 in each account, but when it hit another region template fails due to iam being global. I have been looking over conditions on how to leverage but little confusing. Any assistance or ideas?

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways that you can handle this:

1. Create a single role and provide the ARN of that role to the stacks that need it (via parameter or [import](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-importvalue.html)). This means that you have two things to maintain.
2. Create the role alongside the things that use that role, and add a region identifier to the role name.

Of these, I *much* prefer option #2. Here's an example for a Lambda execution role (`LambdaName` is a stack parameter). Note that I also include the stack name: I like to have everything from the same stack listed together.

```
!Sub "${AWS::StackName}-${AWS::Region}-${LambdaName}-ExecutionRole"
```

The problem with detailed role names like this is that role names have a maximum length of 64 characters. So, I might omit `LambdaName` to keep below this limit (especially stacks that create a single Lambda, where I typically use `AWS::StackName` for the Lambda's name).

Comment: Oh wow! I really appreciate the feedback. Let me look into this on my end and play with. I will provide an update back to this thread. Again, thank you so much.

Comment: I forgot to add I have a central account where I have 3-5 lambdas created and the roles that the lambda functions use already deployed in a separate Cloudformation template no issue there. I am in the process of trying to deploy another template via stackset that has all of the IAM roles that the different functions will assume when my automation runs. There where the issue arises, when trying to deploy the tempate in N. VA and Oregon etc multi region in each account because role already exist.

Comment: Resources:
  ApprovedUntilDatePatchBaselineCrossAccountRole:
    Type: 'AWS::IAM::Role'
    Properties:
      RoleName: approved-until-date-patchbaseline-cross-account-role
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              AWS:
                - arn:aws:iam::209086122903:role/approved-until-date-patchbaselines-ssmpatching-lambda-role

Comment: by chance do you know of a way to only create one IAM role per account? I was testing your method and seems to create two roles vs I only need one. Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you've already created the roles in another stack, then you can use cross-stack references to import the values into your stack. There are a lot of caveats to doing this, and they're all called on on this page: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-importvalue.html

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to handle this in my opinion and only have to use one stack is using Cloudformation 'Conditions'. I was able to create the necessary IAM roles in the target account that I need. These child roles my lambda functions will assume when going through each account and region. Also, it doesnt create two roles for each region as working from a previous response. That method works, but only need one role. here is an example. This method allows my global resources to be created once and other items to duplicate as needed for each region.
Conditions:

```
  RegionCheck: !Equals
    - !Ref "AWS::Region"
    - us-east-1
```

Resources:

```
  ApprovedUntilDatePatchBaselineCrossAccountRole:
    Type: 'AWS::IAM::Role'
    Condition: RegionCheck
    Properties:
      RoleName: approved-until-date-patchbaseline-cross-account-role
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              AWS:
                - arn:aws:iam::<AccountID>/etc
```